# Analogue of Kotlin Iterable.map but for single object

Tags: android, kotlin

I can transform a list with map in one line like this:

```
override suspend fun getAllTxtFile(): List<TxtFileModel> {
    return someDao.getAllTxtFile().map { with(txtFileDataMapper) { it.fromEntityToDomain() } }
}
```

But I don't know how to do it for single class object:

```
override suspend fun getTxtFile(txtFileName: String?): TxtFileModel {
    val txtFile = someDao.getTxtFile(txtFileName)
    val txtFileModel = with(txtFileDataMapper) { txtFile.fromEntityToDomain() }
    return txtFileModel
}
```

So, the difference is that for list I can return a value in one line but for a single object only in 3 lines.

That is not big deal but I wonder if exist some anologue for `.map` but for a single object. I want something like `.mapSingleObject`:

```
override suspend fun getTxtFile(txtFileName: String?): TxtFileModel {
    return someDao.getTxtFile(txtFileName).mapSingleObject{ with(txtFileDataMapper) { it.fromEntityToDomain() } }
}
```

Comment: `.let` works exactly like `.map`, but for one item.

Comment: Why do you use `with` in this peace of code: `val txtFileModel = with(txtFileDataMapper) { txtFile.fromEntityToDomain() }` ? As far as i see you don't use any property or function of `txtFileDataMapper` object.

Comment: Maybe `fromEntityToDomain` is a TxtFile extension function defined within the `txtFileDataMapper`'s class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some functions from Kotlin standard library, such as `let`, `run`, or `with`.

If function `fromEntityToDomain()` is a `TxtFile` extension function defined within the `txtFileDataMapper`'s class, you can use functions mentioned above:

```
override suspend fun getTxtFile(txtFileName: String?): TxtFileModel? = 
        someDao.getTxtFile(txtFileName)?.let { 
            with(txtFileDataMapper) { it.fromEntityToDomain() } 
        }
```